# D3 tree and positioning JQuery UI Dialog with nodes

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, d3.js

I have a D3 tree and need to position JQuery UI Dialog next to the node on right click.

The position of the dialog is not working with `$( "#dialog" ).dialog('option', 'position', [d.x,d.y]);`

```
var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "node")
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
        return "translate(" + source.y0 + "," + source.x0 + ")";
    })
    .on("click", click)
    .on('contextmenu', function(d) {
        d3.event.preventDefault();
        $('#dialog').dialog('option', 'title', d.name);
        $("#dialog").dialog('option', 'position', [d.x, d.y]);
        $('#dialog').dialog('open');
    });
```

The other bits work, just not the position.  Any ideas?  I would like to get the dialog to display just to the left of the right clicked node.

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f89mL5ty/1/)

Comment: Would advise you set the `position` option before executing `open`.

Comment: Also, function is passed `d` but you call `d3.event.preventDefault()`. Don't see where `d3` is defined.

Comment: I believe d3.event is a global variable - see https://www.dashingd3js.com/lessons/d3-and-dom-events

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The position passed to jQuery `dialog` is measured from the top left corner of the current view (regardless the amount scrolled). I highly doubt that these are the `d.x` and `d.y` values, which seem to be coordinates relative to your SVG.

That being said, you can use [`clientX`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/clientX) and [`clientY`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/clientY). If you want to use D3's events, they are `d3.event.clientX` and `d3.event.clientY`:

```
.on( 'contextmenu', function ( d ) {
    d3.event.preventDefault();
    $( '#dialog' ).dialog( 'option', 'title', d.name );
    $( '#dialog' ).dialog( 'open' );
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog('option', 'position', [d3.event.clientX,d3.event.clientY])
 });
```

Edit: according to jQuery [documentation](https://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-position), you should not pass an array of coordinates, but an object instead, like:

```
{my: "left top", at: "left top", of: event }
```

Here is your forked JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/589w62L3/

Comment: Thanks, but the dialog is just being positioned in the centre of the screen, not relative to the node. There is no other positioning happining with dialog elsewhere.  This is with position set before open as updated in the OP.  I think it may be a problem with the dialog position statement.

Comment: `d3.event.clientX` and `Y` will return the position you clicked. I'm afraid there is no much to do unless you provide a working code so we can test the solutions.

Comment: fiddle added to OP

Comment: Are you sure your jQuery part is correct? The documentation says `position` requires an object: https://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-position

Comment: I think my JQuery position is deprecated.  I saw the updated position, but not sure how to use that with a d3 node.